# How to make a mock return 'false' for 'Optional.isPresent()'?

Tags: groovy, spock

I want to mock the statement below which returns `OptionalData`. I want to mock that data such that `Optional.isPresent()` returns `false`.

```groovy
private static Optional<UserList> userListOptional
private static SharedList sharedList

sharedList = SharedList.builder()
  .sharedListId(2000L)
  .collaboratorList(collaboratorLists)
  .build()

userListOptional = Optional.of(
  UserList.builder()
    .userListId(1234)
    .userId(607042)
    .activeFlag(true)
    .userName("UnitedStates")
    .sharedList(sharedList)
    .build()
)

userListRepository.findByUserIdAndSharedListAndActiveFlagTrue(*_) >> userListOptional
```

My code under test is:

```java
Optional<UserList> userListOptional = userListRepository
  .findByUserIdAndSharedListAndActiveFlagTrue(user.getUserId(), sharedList);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please give your own questions some more love. I added syntax highlighting and reformatted the code so as to make it somewhat more readable. Also please use a catchy subject line instead of putting the whole question into it across multiple lines. The complete question belongs into the main text. Your question also is a bit difficult to understand, so please be advised to learn what an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is. Asking MCVE-style questions significantly improves your chances to get helpful answers. Otherwise: garbage in → garbage out.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want an `Optional` returning `false` for `isPresent()`, you don't need to mock the Optional at all but just create an empty one.

Assume we have these simplified application classes:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q62709855;

public class UserList {
  private String name;

  public UserList(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q62709855;

import java.util.Optional;

public class UserListRepository {
  public Optional<UserList> findByUserIdAndSharedListAndActiveFlagTrue(int userId) {
    return Optional.of(new UserList("admins"));
  }
}
```

Then your Spock specification could look like this:

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q62709855

import spock.lang.Specification

class UserListRepositoryTest extends Specification {
  def test() {
    given:
    Optional<UserList> userListOptional = Optional.empty()
    UserListRepository userListRepository = Mock() {
      findByUserIdAndSharedListAndActiveFlagTrue(*_) >> userListOptional
    }

    expect:
    !userListRepository.findByUserIdAndSharedListAndActiveFlagTrue(123).isPresent()
  }
}
```

Of course this test only tests that the mock object actually returns the stubbed return value, but you get the idea. I hope this was what you wanted to know because neither your question itself nor the code snippets you posted are clear enough to communicate your intent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

> Optional.empty()

in Junit tests.

for example:

```
Optional<List<RelationshipDto>> relationshipDtoListOp = Optional.empty();

        when(relationshipRepository.findAllByLearner(learnerId, RelationshipType.PRIMARY)).thenReturn(relationshipDtoListOp);
```

Answer (score 0):

For Mockito, you can use this value, it works like a wonder, it worked for me..

```
Optional<MyClass> myClassObj = Optional.absent();
Mockito.when(serviceClass.getMethodValue(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(myClassObj);
```

It automatically assigns it as Optional.empty on return..Cheers..